# Find area and perimeter using fundamental forms

Tags: differential-geometry, area

This is a question my professor posed, and I'm not understanding how fundamental forms are related to lengths or how to approach this problem.

Suppose a surface has fundamental form $I = du^2 + (u^2+a^2) dv^2$ (for a constant $a$). Consider a triangle bounded by $u = av, u = -av,$ and $v = 1.$

- a) Find its perimeter.
- b) Find its area.
  (recall the infinitesimal length $ds$;   infinitesimal area $dA =$ |x<sub>u</sub> x x<sub>v</sub> | $du$ $dv$ )

Can someone point me in a helpful direction?

Comment: The infinitesimal area formula is useless because we don’t have a parametrized surface in $\Bbb R^3$. You definitely need to study your notes on how you use the first fundamental form to compute lengths and areas. Don’t just expect us to do your homework.

Comment: @TedShifrin This is extremely presumptuous and unfriendly. I'm very new to this forum, I've studied my notes and they were unhelpful. I figured someone here would point me in a good direction to study because I don't even know where to start. I find it distasteful to discourage someone from reaching out for help.

Comment: You need to see it from our side, with tens of thousands of students posting their homework with zero effort.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can understand your frustrations, but I don't think it's very fair to expect that all students take this route. It can be very discouraging to students who do need help.

Comment: So what *is* the first fundamental form? You feed in two vectors and it does what? BTW, if your notes are worthless, download my diff geo text for free. See my profile.

Comment: @tedshifrin It's kinda like a mapping from euclidean space to an intrinsic space based on the tangents right? And I'll take you up on that offer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your surface may be viewed as a region $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $u,v$ and first fundamental form $I = du^2 + (u^2 + a^2)dv^2$. Using this first fundamental form, we can determine the lengths of curves and the areas of regions in the following way.

If $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow S$ is a curve with parameter $s$ and components $u(s),v(s)$, then
$$ \text{Length}(\gamma) = \int_a^b \sqrt{I\left(\tfrac{d\gamma}{ds},\tfrac{d\gamma}{ds}\right)} ds  \,=\, \int_a^b \sqrt{(\tfrac{du}{ds})^2 + (u(s)^2+a^2)(\tfrac{dv}{ds})^2} \,\,ds.$$
If $A \subset S$ is a region parametrised by $u,v$, then
$$ \text{Area}(A) = \int\int_A \sqrt{\text{det}(I)}\, dudv \, = \, \int\int_A \sqrt{u^2 + a^2}\, dudv. $$
So to complete the question, simply parametrise the edges of the triangle and use the first formula to get the perimeter (it's best to parametrise each side seperately and add the lengths at the end), and parametrise the triangle itself and use the second formula to get the area.